# Should I be able to safely rebase a shared branch if I do it on a personal remote?

Tags: git

Right now I'm on a project with multiple people mostly working on the master branch. I do my work on a personal remote, also to the master branch. The problem I run into is when I try to rebase master on my personal remote then push that to origin to reintegrate with everyone else it seems to create duplicate commits and makes a big mess. Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure that are you asking. Rebase is unrelated to remotes, it is all about branches. Please give more info and show what are you doing

Comment: But looks like you are merging rebased branch.

Comment: Do you run `git pull` at any point to get the newest data from the shared repository into your master?

Comment: I git pull from the shared repository into my master all the time. I only rebased the commits on master that were unique to my remote so I thought I would be able to push it to the shared repository without any issues.

Comment: So long as you're not rebasing commits that are already on the shared branch you should be fine. =/

Could you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? An example would be helpful.